# Reset password API Plateform 3.x - must not be accessed before initialization

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

The doc of API Plateform do not provide a great documentation about that, the only thing I found, but this is not working : https://api-platform.com/docs/core/messenger/#using-messenger-with-an-input-object

But when I try this incomplete documentation, I get an error !

> Typed property App\Dto\ResetPasswordRequest::$email must not be
> accessed before initialization

I call the route `POST /api/users/reset_password`

with json body :

```
{"email": "foo@bar.com"}
```

The entity :

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: '`user`')]
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new GetCollection(),
        new Post(processor: UserPasswordHasher::class),
        new Get(),
        new Put(processor: UserPasswordHasher::class),
        new Patch(processor: UserPasswordHasher::class),
        new Delete(),
        new Post(
            name: 'reset_password', 
            status: 202, 
            messenger: 'input', 
            input: ResetPasswordRequest::class, 
            output: false, 
            uriTemplate: '/users/reset_password'
        )
    ],
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['user:read']],
    denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['user:create', 'user:update']],
)]
#[UniqueEntity('email')]
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
...
```

And the DTO :

```
<?php
// api/src/Dto/ResetPasswordRequest.php

namespace App\Dto;

final class ResetPasswordRequest
{
    public string $email;
}
```

And handler :

```
<?php
// api/src/Handler/ResetPasswordRequestHandler.php

namespace App\Handler;

use App\Dto\ResetPasswordRequest;
use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Mime\TemplatedEmail;
use Symfony\Component\Mailer\MailerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Address;
use SymfonyCasts\Bundle\ResetPassword\Exception\ResetPasswordExceptionInterface;
use SymfonyCasts\Bundle\ResetPassword\ResetPasswordHelperInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\Handler\MessageHandlerInterface;


final class ResetPasswordRequestHandler implements MessageHandlerInterface
{

    public function __construct(
        private ResetPasswordHelperInterface $resetPasswordHelper,
        private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
        private MailerInterface $mailer
    ) {}

    public function __invoke(ResetPasswordRequest $forgotPassword)
    {
        die(var_dump($forgotPassword->email));
        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy([
            'email' => $forgotPassword->email,
        ]);


        if (!$user) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            $resetToken = $this->resetPasswordHelper->generateResetToken($user);
        } catch (ResetPasswordExceptionInterface $e) {
            return;
        }

        $email = (new TemplatedEmail())
            ->from(new Address('noreply@foo.ch'))
            ->to($user->getEmail())
            ->subject('Your password reset request')
            ->htmlTemplate('mail/reset_password.html.twig')
            ->context([
                          'resetToken' => $resetToken,
                          'tokenLifetime' => $this->resetPasswordHelper->getTokenLifetime(),
                      ])
        ;

        $this->mailer->send($email);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly are you setting the `$email`-property in your `ResetPasswordRequest` class? I can only see where you're trying to read it. When using typed properties, they either need a default value or you need to set the property before you can access it (or you will get the error you're getting)

Comment: in ResetPasswordRequestHandler : ```$forgotPassword->email```
I thing this is an api plateform issue, the email is never populated

Comment: That reads the property, not setting it though.

Comment: I know, that's all my point : the email is not populated, but I don't know why

Answer (score 1):

This is due to serialization.

Your DTO ResetPasswordRequest.php class would be:

```
<?php

namespace App\Dto;

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

class ResetPasswordRequest
{
    #[Groups(['user:create', 'user:read'])]
    public string $email;
}
```

If you have already done with it or have different approach for this please share.